# Do I need to replace my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

Recently my computer with windows 7 began to lockup regularly even after formatting and reinstalling, after being unable to get windows to work I decided to install linux mint and it seemed to have fixed the problem but sometimes it will crash from i/o errors. I've checked the hard disk with several different programs to diagnose the problem but only one (the one from the manufacturer)  have shown any problems. Before I go out and buy a replacement I want to know, is there anything else that may be causing the problem?

edit: Like FreudianSlip mentioned I ran the motherboard's diagnostics and the hard drive came back with error BIOHD-8 which after some goggling means my hard drives is near death or possibly somethings wrong with the motherboard or BIOS.

Comment: If you suspect a problem with the HDD, and problems persist over multiple installations of an operating system, its best to simply replace the hdd.  You don't really go into specifics so its tough to actually answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check the connection cable between the harddrive and the mainboard.

The I.O Errors can also come from that.

Answer (score 0):

I've (in the past) used a product called SpinRite (https://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) with great results.

I'd strongly recommend using this product - although in your situation (i.e. no important data on there) the cost of purchasing a copy of spinrite may outweigh the costs of simply buying a new hard disk.

The other things I'd check (in line with the answer from konqui) would be the cables, power supply voltages, motherboard connections and memory.  Does your motherboard have any diagnostics you can exercise - if so, give those a good run.